# Can methods be defined outside of a class?

Tags: php

I'm just getting into using classes in php and am coming from a C++ background. Literally every example I've seen shows methods being defined inside of the class definition, and I'm wondering if I can define my class methods outside of the class definition in order to improve readability?

Comment: i dont thinks so. PHp doen'st work like c++.

Comment: You mean "increase readability to C++ developers." You should focus on increasing readability for other PHP developers working on your code.

Comment: I think your idea of readability might not be that popular outside of C++ circles!

Comment: @millimoose - so large classes in php must have GIGANTIC definitions, right? The reason I asked this question was that I'm considering changing the way an application I wrote from using standalone functions to being a class (or a couple of classes), but there are thousands of lines of code..

Comment: @Nate If your class is so huge it would warrant splitting into multiple source files, you should consider splitting it up into *multiple classes*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. PHP 5.4 itroduced [traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which is about as close as you're gonna get.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can in PHP. The function body for class methods can be put fully into external files:

```
class foo
{
    function bar() {
        include('import_method_body.php');
    }
}
```

This works since ages.

Comment: Not quite like C++, but indeed you can do it that way. (I think I would quit my job if I ever found someone had included a _method body_ from another file though)

Comment: Well, take a look at one of the most popular PHP frameworks (Zend), it makes heavy use of that. (I'm not judging about that here ;) )

Comment: @Michael: PHP is an interpreted language I find it hard to compare with C++. e,g, you can register your own protocol wrapper and then do some wired `include 'my://wrap(it.up())';` stuff. And that's then not only *inside*  method bodies (and nothing Zend framework makes use of btw.).

Answer (score 1):

In short, NO you can't do that;
In php every mothod should be inside the class. And that is why php isn't considered to be fully OOP language by some developers i have seen.

Comment: If that's the reason they think PHP isn't fully OOP, they have a lot more to learn about PHP. (it's not fully OOP, but that's the least of its worries)

Comment: @Michael amen brother, amen :)

Comment: YOu know what, i also agree with them. Take an example of asp.net. It is like camparing 100 marks with 55 marks

Comment: @DigitalAssets That's a nonsensical comparison. More apt would be comparing ASP.NET MVC with, say, Zend Framework / CakePHP / Symphony / CodeIgniter / whatever.

Comment: All things that you mentioned, there is only one answer to these i-e .Net Framework